# What specification should I use for documenting REST APIs?

Tags: api, rest, jax-rs, swagger, hydra-core

I've been looking for automatic creating the documentation for the REST API of a project I'm working on. First, Hydra (http://www.hydra-cg.com) shows up with an interesting idea for designing Web APIs. Later some colleagues recommend me to use Swagger 2.0 (http://swagger.io) as code generator. Then, I realise that both specifications can solve the same problem of documenting the REST API.

What are the downsides/benefits of using Hydra or Swagger specification?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swagger is well established and supports a wide range of languages and frameworks. It doesn't force you to write the API in a specific style and it should be a better fit if you just want to document an existing API.

Hydra looks like interesting framework to develop REST APIs but has yet to be adopted by any standards organizations *and* the industry to make it a real standard. It's just an unofficial draft by a W3C community group for now. It also seems very new and provides experimental tools for some languages, which don't seem ready for production. I'm not even sure if you can integrate the framework with an existing API without changing the API significantly.

As stated by inf3erno, Hydra is more focused on the original definition of REST services and generated documentation is just a byproduct. On a first glance it seems to me that they are using  principles similar to [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS) and try to formalize that technique using vocabularies. I think there is good reason to stay with the more simple modern definition of REST services though and don't make development to complicated by adding HATEOAS or vocabularies.

Comment: I agree, hydra is currently not production ready, so if you need a tool now, then choose swagger, or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Hydra is about creating a REST specific vocab, so after it became a standard, every REST API can use that vocab, and it will be possible to write general REST clients, just like browsers are for human users on the web currently. That is real REST. Current so called REST APIs don't fulfill the uniform interface constraint, because they use non-standard solutions. Hydra will solve this problem. It's just an insignificant detail, that it is possible to generate documentation from an API specific vocab if it is described with hydra terms.

A don't know what swagger is, but it appears to be a non-standard solution to the same problem.